# Use multiple remotes for dokku deployment

Tags: dokku

So I'm trying to deploy the same app on multiple dokku server instances.
So far I just found the standart way of adding the dokku remote like so:

`git remote add dokku dokku@dokku.me:ruby-getting-started`

I do not think I can add another remote like:

`git remote add server2 dokku@dokku2.me:ruby-getting-started`

Right?

So how would I approach this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have two servers on different IP addresses? Should be possible to add your remote pointing to the IP address. 

git remote add dokku2 dokku@<IP ADDRESS>:ruby-getting-started

Comment: @JorgeNajeraT Doesen't the remote need to be named `dokku` to trigger all the post deploy scripts and stuff?

Comment: No, they will run automatically after the deployment it's done. If you use for example dokku-cli there you will have some problems, because it looks for the remote named dokku and you can only have one.